# Book recommendations: Olympiad Geometry

Tags: geometry, contest-math, book-recommendation, combinatorial-geometry

As a 10th grader who'll take the ICSE exam in Q1 2024, I am planning to attempt the Indian Olympiad Qualifier in Mathematics next year, and quite hopefully RMO, INMO, and IMO afterward. I have found good sources to learn about other topics like number theory, algebra, and combinatorics. However, I am struggling to find books from where I can learn about Olympiad geometry. Any recommendations for books that explain the theoretical aspects of geometry and combinatorial geometry properly?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of geometry books on Amazon after a quick Google search. That is if you want to go out of your way to spend some money.

Comment: https://www.awesomemath.org/shop/about-awesomemath-books/  I see, books shown at https://www.awesomemath.org/shop/  and here is one: https://www.awesomemath.org/product/introduction-to-olympiad-geometry/

Answer (score 4):

The classical reference is

- *Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads* by *Evan Chen* (you can find virtually all solutions at AOPS).

In post-Soviet countries, we also appreciate

- *Problems in Plane Geometry* by *V. Prasolov*. Maybe it's outdated to meet the current IMO level, but it is definitely worth a look, at least because it has full solutions to all problems (many of which are timeless classics) of a broad range of topics.
- *Geometry in Figures* by *A. Akopyan* (a more modern and a way more difficult book.)

Going through these books in combination with *solving olympiad problems* from national olympiads worldwide as well as *reading specialised handouts and articles* on geometry (you can find them, say, at AOPS) will be enough to succeed at most olympiads.

P.S. Don't overlearn theory: olympiad geometry is basically about little tricks that you gain after practice. In real life, (accessible) national-level problems usually involve nothing more than basic things like angle chasing. Heavy machinery is needed are usually required for the most difficult tasks in a set, but you won't be able to solve them unless you master the basics.